# Link with Embedded Icon Not Firing with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, menu, href, menuitem

I have a menu list where icons are placed next to the menu label. One menu item has a sub-menu that is expanded with JavaScript. If I click anywhere within the menu item, the sub-menu expands. However, if I click on the icon embedded in the menu item or the label, the sub-menu won't expand. All other menu items that don't use JavaScript to expand sub-menus fire correctly when clicking on the icon or other parts of the menu item.

```js
// Show an element
var show = function (elem) {

  // Get the natural height of the element
  var getHeight = function () {
    elem.style.display = 'block'; // Make it visible
    var height = elem.scrollHeight + 'px'; // Get it's height
    elem.style.display = ''; //  Hide it again
    return height;
  };

  var height = getHeight(); // Get the natural height
  elem.classList.add('is-visible'); // Make the element visible
  elem.style.height = height; // Update the max-height

  // Once the transition is complete, remove the inline max-height so the content can scale responsively
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    elem.style.height = '';
  }, 350);

};

// Hide an element
var hide = function (elem) {

  // Give the element a height to change from
  elem.style.height = elem.scrollHeight + 'px';

  // Set the height back to 0
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    elem.style.height = '0';
  }, 1);

  // When the transition is complete, hide it
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    elem.classList.remove('is-visible');
  }, 300);

};

// Toggle element visibility
var toggle = function (elem, timing) {

  // If the element is visible, hide it
  if (elem.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
    hide(elem);
    return;
  }

  // Otherwise, show it
  show(elem);

};

// Listen for click events
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

  // Make sure clicked element is our toggle
  if (!event.target.classList.contains('toggle')) return;

  // Prevent default link behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get the content
  var content = document.querySelector(event.target.hash);
  if (!content) return;

  // Toggle the content
  toggle(content);

}, false);
```

```css
ul {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 230px;
}

li {
  color: #404040;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: -0.4px;
  line-height: 1.025rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

li ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li img {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

li a {
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.875rem 1.5rem 1.025rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #f2f6f9;
}

li span {
  position: relative;
  top: -.25rem;
}

li li {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.toggle {
  border-left: 5px solid #015295;
  padding-left: calc(1.5rem - 5px);
}

.toggle-content {
  display: none;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
}

.toggle-content.is-visible {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://isitchristmas.com">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/263/263115.svg" width="20" height="20" alt=""><span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li style="background-color: #f2f6f9;"><a class="toggle" href="#example"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/263/263078.svg" width="20" height="20" alt=""><span>Billing</span>
    </a>
    <div class="toggle-content" id="example">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://isitchristmas.com">Premium Statement</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://isitchristmas.com">Payment Summary</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://isitchristmas.com">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/263/263058.svg" width="20" height="20" alt=""><span>Employees</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://isitchristmas.com"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/263/263146.svg" width="20" height="20" alt=""><span>Claims</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://isitchristmas.com"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/263/263122.svg" width="20" height="20" alt=""><span>My Plans</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I don't know why clicking on the icon embedded in the link would prevent the JavaScript from firing. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the "event.target" returns the exact DOM element, so in your code, when you click on the "img" or on the "span", the "event.target" will return

`<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/263/263078.svg" width="20" height="20" alt="">`

or

`<span>Billing</span>`

In order to prevent this you should use : `.closest('a')` it will go to the closest element that fit the description.

```
  // Make sure clicked element is our toggle
  if (!event.target.closest('a').classList.contains('toggle')) {
    return;
  }

  // Prevent default link behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get the content
  console.log(event.target.closest('a').hash);
  var content = document.querySelector(event.target.closest('a').hash);
  if (!content) return;
```

This is my small modification to your code, it should work now.

To understand more about `.closest()` read here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest